# Is it possible to add comments to NextJS .env.local files?

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables

In a typical NodeJS .env file I can provide comments with the # character. If I try the same in a NextJS .env.local file it just ignores the `#` and reads the whole line.

I can't see anything in the docs to advise: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Example `.env.local` file:

```
TEST="localhost" 
ENV=dev
```

Comment: Added it to the questions. Thanks!

Comment: And if you comment one of those lines like `# TEST="localhost"`, it still shows if you  log `process.env.TEST` to the console?

Comment: `.env` files are not specific to Next.js, they're a thing on their own used by a million and one things, and they support comments just fine, but only full line comments. Lots of pages on the web if you search for "how to comment env file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js doesn't recognize comments on the same line as values, so this would not work and you would get the whole line as the value.

```
ENV=dev # dev | prod | stage
```

However, this still works

```
# dev | prod | stage
ENV=dev
```

BTW, in next.js app you need to prefix variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` if you want the values translated to the frontend part of next app, otherwise the variables would only work in Node.js (api part of next).